# Getting error: system error -2147024786, setup wizard ended prematurely while installing MYSQL CONNECTOR

Tags: mysql-connector

The error message "**Failed to open XML file (system error -2147024786)**" and The error message "****Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error**" while installing MYSQL CONNECTOR...
I am a beginner in SQL and I am still learning the basics. I would appreciate any help or resources that you can provide.
I would be glad if anyone could assist me with this..

Comment: This error has nothing to do with sql, mysql, or databases. Try restarting the installation or even re-download the installer for mysql connector. If the issue persists, you need to ask mysql for support if thos us their mysql connector driver which installation fails.